import filename as fn fails in python 3.11
I have a scheduled task that runs a python script.
The python script imports a bunch of functions from another python script held in the same directory.
- dir
   - script.py
   - functions.py

I call functions.py with:
import functions as paxf

This has worked for the past 4 months.
Now it returns the following error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'functions'

I have not made any changes to the scripts, and am on python 3.11.
I tried updated the path location of functions with:

import .functions,
import parent.functions,
import home.parent.functions,

but receive the same error.
Any suggestions as to what can be going wrong?

updated question to correct this

What has changed since the last 4 months? Did you upgrade the Python version? Then you probably need to reinstall the dir package so that it is in the Python module search path again. Installed packages are separated between Python versions.

@MohitBurkule That's irrelevant for the error and from the code it looks like it isn't supposed to have it

What OS are you using? I would suspect in the first case that your PythonPath does not include the functions.py location. Solutions include adding it to PythonPath or if running as a task to specify from which location to run from. I.e run from dir.

On Windows, you can use alternative Python modules to achieve file locking or similar functionality. One popular option is portalocker, which provides a cross-platform way to lock files.
you can try to check it out ,hope this helps you.
More information about portalocker can be found at GitHub link here :
https://github.com/WoLpH/portalocker
